# low consuming Virtualization for Ubuntu to use Windows XP

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

Looking for low consuming Virtualization for Ubuntu to use Windows XP. Need to open small application with Windows XP using small interface window

Trying to save computing resources, so I'm looking for something small and neat

Comment: Windows XP is not small...   I have good luck with VirtualBox, although VMWare also works.  However, have you tried your application under `wine`?  A surprisingly large number of apps work just great in `wine` in native Linux, no VM required.

Answer (score 0):

Try QEMU:
its a powerful and flexible open-source emulator that can be used to run virtual machines. It's relatively lightweight and can be run from the command line. However, it might require some configuration and command-line knowledge.

To install QEMU on Ubuntu, you can use the following command:
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm